# How can I match specific portion of a URL in Squid

Tags: squid

I want to create an acl in Squid such that specific locations within a domain can be blocked.

For example:

I want to allow the domain example.com and all the pages except the following.

```
example.com/home.php
example.com/#!/
example.com/home.php#!/profile.php
```

I want to have an exact match of the pattern in the URL. If the pattern is not
matched it should allow otherwise deny.

Can anyone please suggest me how do I do this ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have it configured is like this:
I have a file with the blocked url patters
and in the squid.conf I have the following lines

```
acl blocked url_regex "/path/to/my/file"
http_access deny blocked
```

And that's all. "/path/to/my/file" looks like this

```
porn # for every url having the string porn on it
orkut.com $ for the full domain
.*avg.com/.*\.bin$ # for the url with  avg.com domain and asking for the file *.bin
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: I tried your suggestions it works fine. But if I allow a domain and try to restrict some pages it's not working for HTTPS. I figured out that Squid sees the URL in encrypted form once the connection is established. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Filtering https urls based on other criteria than site name is not possible, since the squid doesn't see the url, which is encrypted between the client and the origin server, the method used is CONNECT. To filter that you have to execute a man-in-the-middle attack, which is outside the scope of squid (plus the users will be notified of that and you loose most of the https security)